# Why @UpdateTimestamp is setting a value by default on entity creation?

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, annotations, audit

I have an entity with a field to save the date when the entity was updated. I'm using the annotations below:

```
@Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@UpdateTimestamp
@Column(name = "updated_at", nullable = true)
private Date updatedAt;
```

I want `updatedAt` in `null` as default value but I have as default value the same date when the entity was created.

In my `@Service` class I save the entity like this:

```
visitorRepository.saveAndFlush(visitor)
```

There is a way to save my updatedAt in null as default value using @UpdateTimestamp?

Comment: Check de documentation deeply, but Im 99% sure that is not posible. When you are saving, really it is a type of update. If you have, for example, 2 columns: one for update time stamp and another for insert time stamp, when you save an object and no update it after, both will have same value,

Comment: Is exactly what is happening, `createdAt` and `updatedAt` have the same value after entity creation. `createdAt` have the `@CreationTimestamp` annotation.

Comment: `@UpdateTimestamp` uses `GenerationTiming.ALWAYS` so a value is always generated (either INSERT or UPDATE).  Not sure if will work, but perhaps try `@Column(... insertable = false)`.

Comment: Is not bad behavior. If you have same value in both columns (insert and update timestamp) it means that user hasn't edited anything (yeah, thats obvious). Usually, the insert time stamp is marked as not updateable. So, you have an easy way to audit, ¿why do you need the update field as null? it my help

Comment: I need to return the list of objects that are not updated then I think that can be reached whit that field. Meanwhile, I will remove the annotation and handle the date manually.

Comment: This is actually a nice behaviour, but the worst thing is that it actually does not always set exactly the same value, as a result the tests are flakily failing when comparing these fields:  `expected: 2021-06-18T12:20:36.492604+02:00[Europe/Berlin] (java.time.ZonedDateTime)
but was : 2021-06-18T12:20:36.492092+02:00[Europe/Berlin] (java.time.ZonedDateTime)`

Answer (score 4):

As [Andrew S](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6650475/andrew-s) suggested [in a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66574436/why-updatetimestamp-is-setting-a-value-by-default-on-entity-creation/70562903#comment117689236_66574436), a combination of `@UpdateTimestamp` and `@Column(... insertable = false)` did the trick form me.